# Forms e Iframes

Tags: javascript, html

É possível utilizar um `<iframe>` dentro de um `<form>`?

Estou fazendo um código onde passo um `id` na `<div>` e dentro um `<form>` com outro `id`, assim dentro do `<form>` quero chamar um `<iframe>` onde se encontra o meu conteúdo.

Código resumido:

```
<tr>
    <td height="300" width="" class="tb-conteudo" colspan="4" align="left" valign="top" >  
        <div id="div_usua" class="conteudo" style="display: none; padding-top:5px;">
            <form id="form_usua">
                <table align="left" border="0" width="2%">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <iframe style="border-radius:20px;" scrolling="no" src="../sai_cada_usua/menu_com_abas_usua.php" width="900" height="400" >
                            </iframe>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </form> 
            </table>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Código completo : [JSF](http://jsfiddle.net/SNxS4/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em relação à sua pergunta:
 "É possível utilizar um  dentro de um ?" a resposta é: **depende do que quer fazer**.

Se quer inserir dados dentro da iframe e quer que eles sejam colhidos pela form quando a submeter, então a resposta é **não**.

Se a pergunta é somente técnica, ou seja se pode ter uma iframe dentro de um form para mostrar conteudo ou publicidade, a resposta é **sim**.

Porem se o conteúdo da iFrame está no mesmo dominio, o melhor seria usar AJAX para carregar o conteudo para dentro da mesma página, em vez de comnplicar e criar uma outra página/sessão (que é o que a iframe faz).

Comment: obrigado, tirou a duvida que eu tinha em mente!